# Using mysql and like statement match a full word to a query

Tags: mysql, string, wildcard, sql-like, names

Given: table 'people', and a string 'bob joe'

Return: 'bob a joe' row, NOT the bobby joel row.

```
name
'bob a joe'
'ana l lee'
'bobby joel'
```

I would like to ONLY return bob joe, NOT bobby joel:

```
SELECT name FROM people 
WHERE name Like '%bob%'
AND name like '%joe%';
```

This code returns both the bob and bobby names. Names in my database are not always first last, they are sometimes last first middle, so 'bob %' does not remedy the problem. It is true that

```
SELECT name FROM people 
WHERE name LIKE '%bob %' OR name LIKE '% bob%' 
AND name LIKE '%joe %' OR name LIKE '% joe%'
```

would solve this problem, but I'm looking for a possibly easier or better solution

Thanks so much
Will

Comment: how about 2 columns, firstname and lastname in your database? :)

Comment: `Where trim(name) like 'bob%' and trim(name) like '%joe'`  don't want the percent on begining nor on end.  Just want 2 %'s  Though this is extremely hackish as bobby joe would be returned.  The only way I can see to really do this is search for 1st space from left and first space from irght as first and last names and then join on those only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `like` to find only complete words in any given order, you have to write down all 3 variations, because there is no flag for `start of a word` in `like`. So you have to write down

```
SELECT name FROM people 
WHERE (name LIKE 'bob %' OR name LIKE '% bob %' or name LIKE '% bob')
  and (name LIKE 'joe %' OR name LIKE '% joe %' or name LIKE '% joe');
```

to cover all possibilities (start, middle and end).

Another (fast) possibility (apart from splitting the names into seperate columns) to find complete words is to use a [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). The fulltext index will allow you to search for full words that have a minimum lenght that is given by `innodb_ft_min_token_size` (for InnoDB) and `ft_min_word_len` (for MyISAM), you can set these options in your config file. The default value is 3 for innodb and 4 for myisam, so 'joe' would be fine on innodb. (Another thing to keep in mind: there is a stopword table with with very very common english words that will not be included in the index, like 'are' or 'for' (the fulltext index is normally used to index full sentences rather than just names). You can change that table by setting the [stopwords options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)).

Add a fulltext index on your `name`-column (if you change the options, you have to recreate the index).

```
create fulltext index idx_ft_people_name on people (name);
```

and then use `match against` to find the words

```
select * from people
where match(`name`) against ('+joe +bob' in boolean mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Solarflare. I really like your syntax on that statement a lot more than the way I had it, and this is easy to build in a for loop through my manipulator, which is matlab.

This other route looks tough from a technical standpoint but if I see a large time lag in the first strategy I'll resort to it.

Appreciate the help,
Will